# Leaflet Map: Tooltip on clicking instead on mouseover a marker

Tags: javascript, leaflet, tooltip

I want to have a tooltip on clicking my marker, but I don't find a way to make this.  Leaflet seems to open tooltips only with mouseover.

This is my code:

```
var marker = L.marker([x1, y1], {icon: myIcon})
.addTo(map)
.bindTooltip('<?=$desc[$i]?>', {direction:'top', sticky: false, opacity:0.8, offset:[0, -22] });
```

Thank you for having a look at this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can:

1. Override `_initTooltipInteractions` function in [`Layer` class](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/bc918d4bdc2ba189807bc207c77080fb41ecc196/src/layer/Tooltip.js#L302).
2. Add another method, let's say `bindClickableTooltip`, which shares the
   same logic with `bindTooltip`. but instead of calling [_initTooltipInteractions](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/bc918d4bdc2ba189807bc207c77080fb41ecc196/src/layer/Tooltip.js#L282), calls another method which has got your custom logic inside. You should remove these two lines

```
events.mouseover = this._openTooltip;
events.mouseout = this.closeTooltip;
```

and replace them by

```
events.click = /* a function which handles opening and closing tooltips */
```

(Something like line 316 for touch devices)

Comment: This is your periodic reminder that stuff starting with `_` is meant to be private, is not documented, and should be treated with extra care.

Comment: @IvanSanchez Yes sure but I don't find it applied to leaflet.

Comment: In the Layer class the two lines are: events.mouseover = this._openTooltip;
events.mouseout = this.closeTooltip;

Comment: "events.click"  must be  "e.click". Then it works.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to add an event handler to [toggle](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#layer-toggletooltip) its own tooltip, e.g.:

```js
marker
  .bindTooltip('foobar', { sticky: false })
  .on('click', function(ev) {
    marker.toggleTooltip();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but will not work.
I tried this:

```
var marker = L.marker([x1, y1], {icon: myIcon})
.addTo(map)
.bindTooltip('<?=$desc[$i]?>', {direction:'top', sticky: false, opacity:0.8, offset:[0, -22] });
marker.on('click', function(e) {
        e.target.closeTooltip();
      });
marker.on('dblclick', function(e) {
        e.target.openTooltip();     
      });
```

This will work, but isn't perfect. Because first the tooltip comes automatically on mouseover, then I click to close it and then I must dblclick to open it again. It seems it cannot be prevented to open the tooltip on mouseover, or?

Comment: Is this an answer to your question, or a reply to someone else? If it is not a stand-alone answer in its own right, it is best to add it as an update to the question, then ping the relevant answer author with a comment.